# How can I install gufw on fedora?

Tags: fedora, security, software-installation, firewall

I want to install `gufw` on my Fedora, but I do not know how to do that.
I tried to install with the `dnf` package manager command but it doesn't work and gets this output:

```
No match for argument: gufw
Error: Unable to find a match
```

So, I did an `apt-get` and again I got negative result:

```
E: Couldn't find package gufw
```

1. How can I successfully install gufw?
2. I want to control each app's access to the internet, so is there any firewall app other than `gufw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [rpmsphere](https://rpmsphere.github.io/) software repository which contains the `gufw` package.

The following works for Fedora 30, with `root` rights:

```bsh
# install rpmsphere repository
rpm -Uvh 'https://github.com/rpmsphere/noarch/blob/master/r/rpmsphere-release-30-1.noarch.rpm?raw=true'

# install gufw
dnf install gufw
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not start on Fedora 30 due `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland`.

So, change `/usr/bin/gufw` to:

```
c_user=$(whoami)
pkexec gufw-pkexec $c_user
xhost si:localuser:root
```

Also check `/usr/bin/gufw-pkexec` for the correct location of "`gufw.py`"

Mine is like this one:

```
LOCATIONS=(
"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gufw/gufw.py"
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gufw/gufw.py"
"/usr/share/gufw/gufw/gufw.py"
)

for ((i = 0; i < ${#LOCATIONS[@]}; i++))
do
    if [[ -e "${LOCATIONS[${i}]}" ]]; then
        python3.7 ${LOCATIONS[${i}]} $1
    fi
done
```